# Can Magento handle configurable swatches functionality?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, swatches

Can Magento handle configurable swatches functionality?
I have two products with different attributes. A product goes through different situations, let me explain it:

First attribute is size with options of 1 2 3 and second attribute is color with options of 4 5 6. My first product is size 1 with color 4 and second product is size 2 with color 5. Can Magento disable other options as I click on size 2 and just show me color 5 only in product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how the configurable products work.
if you have 2 configurable attributes (size, color) you need to select first the size (you can set the order in the backend) and then you will see for colors only the options available for the selected size.

Comment: as i click on first option like size the options of second attributes with be affected? just using dropdown ? can i use with 3 or more attribute? thanks for helping...

Comment: it works for as many attributes you need. The rule is the values for an attribute depend on the values of the attributes above.